# Expression first difference Erlang Loss formula

Tags: queueing-theory

I am currently working on a small optimization problem in which I need to find an optimal number of servers for an objective function that incorporates the Erlang Loss formula. To this end, I have been searching for an expression for the first order difference of the Erlang Loss formula with respect to the number of servers, i.e. $B(E,m+1)-B(E,m)$, where *m* is the number of servers and $B(E,m)$ is given by:

$B(E,m)={\dfrac  {{\dfrac  {E^{m}}{m!}}}{\sum _{{i=0}}^{m}{\dfrac  {E^{i}}{i!}}}}$

Unfortunately, until now I can't derive or find such an expression (if it exists) and was wondering whether one on this forum could help me out?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Consider the $M/G/c/c$ system consisting of $c$ servers, no queue and load $\rho := \lambda \, \mathbb{E}[B]$, where $\lambda$ is the arrival rate and $B$ the service time. The probability that an arriving job finds all servers busy is called the Erlang loss probability and is denoted by $B(c,\rho)$.

The Erlang loss probability satisfies a recursion, see [Section 11.3 (page 116) of these lecture notes](http://www.win.tue.nl/~iadan/queueing.pdf),

\begin{equation}
B(c,\rho) = \frac{\rho B(c - 1,\rho)}{c + \rho B(c - 1,\rho)}.
\end{equation}

This recursion can be rewritten to

\begin{equation}
\frac{c}{\rho} B(c,\rho) - B(c - 1,\rho) = B(c,\rho) B(c - 1,\rho),
\end{equation}

but I do not think that this is what you were hoping for.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I already knew this recursion as it makes the computation of $B(c,ρ)$ efficient. However, I was indeed not aiming at  this but at the first order difference of $B(c,ρ)$, i.e. $B(c+1,ρ)$-$B(c,ρ)$. But thanks in any case!

Answer (score 0):

You will find the answer in the textbook:
[Teletraffic Engineering](http://orbit.dtu.dk/files/118473571/Teletraffic_34342_V_B_Iversen_2015.pdf)
in section 4.6.5